# Syncing offline Mysqlite to a Remote Database

Tags: database, data-synchronization

I am working on a project where one of the requirements is the app working in offline mode. So I created an offline MySQLite database, which is the copy of the online DB. Now in the android app the employees will do their job while some of the rows in some of the tables will get updated, or some rows will get inserted, but never deleted.

I went with the "Version" method, where I added a column "Version" to the tables, and each time a row gets updated it will increment the version.

The problem is with the insert part. The app is multiuser, if there were 5 rows in the table before the app could no longer connect to the remote database (thus the app must use the offline DB) and if User 1 adds 2 rows and User 2 adds 2 rows too, in their respective offline databases (on different device) they will both have the same IDs and initially, I wanted to check maxID from remote DB and maxID from offline mysqli DB and insert all new rows to online DB, but this wont work.

Any easy solutions how to synch new rows of offline DB to remote DB once connection is back online?

Answer (score 0):

syncing data using id is not good idea 
you should make a update request from you mobile app to server that send it's time stamp of last update (and if you don't add row from you offline devise app to remote server db is so much easy ) 

you should request where created or updated row is newer than you mobile timestamp

ps: in app database for android is SQLite , didn't know you can use other db